# Extract information (especially date of expiry) from RSA certificate file

Tags: certificate, rsa

I have a RSA signed certificate file (x.rsa). I think, the certificate contains some information like the date of expiry.

How can I extract those information?

Comment: Please read some of the [help documents](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to ask a more specific and answerable question. Thanks.

Comment: with some tool, with some programming language? please provide more details.

Comment: A tool would be fine.